# Should a feature branch of forked repository ever be merged to origin main?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Let's consider, 3 people are working in a project and they are using `git`.
Can the project repository be in any one of their github accounts. Or is it more convenient to host the remote project repository in a new account?

Now, one of them will work on a feature. So, he will `fork` the repository, clone it, `git`, create feature branch, make commits in the feature branch and then `git push origin feature`. Then, create a merge request from github site
Then, what should he do?
Should he merge `origin feature` branch to `origin main`? Or delete the `feature branch`? Or keep it untouched?
Should any commit be made in the feature branch after the merge request is accepted and closed.
**At a more broad level, the question is:**
**What does workflow look like(what are the conventional steps) when using git in a team project? What is a complete Gitflow cycle?**

*Note: Please feel free to edit the question, if u think it is not framed correctly. Also help, if what steps I have enumerated is wrong or some pieces are missing.*

Comment: I suppose, this question has to be 1) spitted into at least 2 separate questions: a) team-based workflows of devel b) Gitflow 2) both have to be moved to Software Engineering site and *first suggested question can't be answered* as "opinon-based" on any site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Git (and even more with Git + Github) you have **a lot** of possible workflows for team-based developments, you have to define applicable and usable *for your team*: everybody have own habits and mileage may|have vary

You can:

- Use single repo or forks
- Use personal repo and add collaborators to it or have "organization" + "org. repo" + "org. members"
- Use PR (pure GitHub specific) or enable just merge branches
- Use GitFlow or GitHubFlow or Trunk-based develpment or ...

Comment: Can you please provide some reference links on this

Comment: please provide some reference